# OOP Python Problems

Tags: python, oop

I learned Object Oriented Programming recently and I have these Problems
when I make run for this code , I have this error
How Can I Fix it ?

```
class Grade:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.information = kwargs
    def grade(self):
        g = self.information['grade']
        print(g , "Grade")
    def students(self):
        s = self.information['students']
        print("students : ",s)
    def chairs(self):
        c = self.information['chairs']
        print("Chairs : ",c)
class school(Grade):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self._grades = kwargs
    def classes(self):
        print("YOU HAVE IN THE SCHOLL ",self._grades["classes"],"classes")  
    def students(self):
        super().students()   
first = Grade(grade="first" , students=20,chairs=15)
fir_g = school(classes=9)
fir_g.students()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\python\OOP.py", line 27, in <module>
    fir_g.students()
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\python\OOP.py", line 19, in students
    super(school,self).students()
  File "c:\Users\hp\Desktop\python\OOP.py", line 8, in students
    s = self.information['students']
AttributeError: 'school' object has no attribute 'information'
```

How can Fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to run the `__init__` for the inherited class, as that's where you define `information`:

```
class school(Grade):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self._grades = kwargs
```

And that should then have `information` defined. It's important to always run the inherited class's `__init__` method as it's not run automatically.

Note that this means you'll need to pass any arguments for `Grade` into school as well though. Although, it seems this isn't the structure you would want. Surely `school` would be above grades, so why have it inherit from `Grade`? I strongly suggest you rethink the structure of your classes and how you want them to interact with each other. Maybe you want a method in `school` where you can add a `Grade` object, or something like that.